# Unexpected flow error when determining if object has attributes

Tags: flowtype

Given the following type:

```
/* @flow */

type Vehicle = {
  make?: string,
  model?: string,
};

const vehicle: Vehicle = {
  make: 'Ford',
  model: 'Focus',
};
```

If I wanted to make sure that the `make` and `model` attributes were defined before using them I would expect the following to work:

```
const hasAttributes = vehicle.make && vehicle.model;
if (hasAttributes) {
  console.log(`${vehicle.make} ${vehicle.model}`);
}
```

However flow throws an error saying that `make` and `model` could be undefined and so can't be coerced into a string.

This code does work however:

```
if (vehicle.make && vehicle.model) {
  console.log(`${vehicle.make} ${vehicle.model}`);
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Here's 
[playground example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBqeAFgJYDGMBAvGAN6phgC2AhgNZ4D8AXGAGcMAJzIA7AOYAaJqzgATPDD6CR46agC+AbnQU4YoWABupStX7FyVWg1nsu-AOQAxOMPlOZzFgqXO3CgBXAS8tXVR9QwwwEjYBAEEMNQAjIIw8ATA6U2tqADoHAgAyYpMzG0K-GF0yKDAACjjE5NE0jIEASjtmKIE4AvgJBoADABJ6XPM8Qs48TTAJqcrfRRhNEc7dTXQ6xuWCorBS8ryZ1aVuxl6DfsG4YfHJisO5haWX8+qNra0gA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two caveats here. First, most visible, is with this line...

```
const hasAttributes = vehicle.make && vehicle.model;
```

... which doesn't do what you expect it to do. Instead of returning `true` or `false`, `&&` operator [returns either the first operand, if it's falsy, or the last one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). That's why `hasAttributes` value will never be strictly equal to `true` in your case (as both `make` and `model` properties are strings). But with `=== true` you check for strict equality.

Ironically, Flow doesn't spot this glitch - because it's not its task. But you can make it more explicit, for example:

```
const hasAttributes = vehicle.make && vehicle.model;
(hasAttributes: boolean);
```

... and now you'll see the corresponding warning. The fix is rather trivial:

```
const hasAttributes = Boolean(vehicle.make && vehicle.model);
```

Still, it won't fix another, real problem. Flow is spotting the potential output of `undefined` values  because it's somewhat pessimistic in these situations. There's a whole [slew of similar issues](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2728) on Flow's Github.

The point is, using a separate variable confuses the checker. That's why two all but identical snippets:

```
const hasAttributes = vehicle.make && vehicle.model;
if (hasAttributes) { // output vehicle
```

... and ...

```
if (vehicle.make && vehicle.model) { // output vehicle
```

... are treated differently.

Comment: That is a fair point but neither of your suggestions work. In fact even checking that the attributes are `typeof string` doesn't work: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBqeAFgJYDGMBAvGAN6phgC2AhgNZ4D8AXGAGcMAJzIA7AOYAaJqzgATPDD6CR46agC+AbnQU4YoWABupStX7FyVWg1nsu-AOQAxOMPlOZzFgqXO3CgBXAS8tXVR9QwwwEjYBAEEMNQAjIIw8ATA6bHw4KBMzGwA6B1oaOichUUknMAAyerBcvHzC62pSvxhsirAqtVrdMgKACjjE5NE0jKyKnOEgvABKO2YogThO+AlRgAMAEnpTDrxSzjxNMCOT8zPfRRhNPeXdTXQRsFHbkrKGpp+nQeSlWjHWBk22zgu0OxyKQIuVxu8Pu3Wery0QA

Comment: I've updated the question with your section suggestion which still throws an error.

Comment: Ok thanks - it looks like the pessimistic refinements if the cause of the issues (https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations)